# How can I test if a time-series data satisfies Markov's property and it is a martingale?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, markov-process, martingale

My question is about investigating some properties of time-series.

1. How can I test if my time-series data satisfies Markov's property?
2. How can I test if my time-series data is a martingale?

I wonder if there are some measures to quantify the fit of above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to look up standard stationarity tests.

Markov property amounts to having a auto correlation statistically equal to zero.

Martingale means that the series is stationary around a constant value.